# Does a callback complete before being called again?

Tags: ros, thread, callback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Suppose I have a subscriber with a callback C. C manipulates a number of global variables and then calls a second method M, that builds a message from those global variables and publishes the message.

I am now wondering: Is is possible that C and M interfere, i.e., that M uses global variables that have been modified by a different call to C? Or, stated differently, is it possible to call C before the previous call to C has returned?

I was not able to figure out if `ros::getGlobalCallbackQueue()->callAvailable` blocks till completion. If interference in this situation can happen, how does one usually deal with it?

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222130/does-a-callback-complete-before-being-called-again?/) by [Jay4Ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25243/jay4ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2015-12-08

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Callback execution is single-threaded, unless you setup things differently, by using a Multithreaded or Asynchronous spinner fi. See also [roscpp/Overview/Callbacks and Spinning](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Callbacks%20and%20Spinning).

Btw, this has been asked (and answered) many times before. A quick search immediately turned up [ROS callbacks, threads and spinning](http://answers.ros.org/question/53055/ros-callbacks-threads-and-spinning/) fi.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-12-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jay4Ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25243/jay4ros/) on 2015-12-08**:
Hey! I saw the question you linked before, but I must have missed "Single thread spinner: the default one, takes the messages contained in a callback queue and process the callbacks one by one **while blocking the execution of the thread that called it**." Thanks!

**Comment by [Jay4Ros](https://answers.ros.org/users/25243/jay4ros/) on 2015-12-08**:
Oh, I guess if a program is single threaded a callback can only be called one by one.... My bad!